# How to use losetup to emulate an optical drive that can be a recording target?

Tags: linux, audio, dd, cd-drive

On a Linux system, I am intending to convert some audio files (mp3) and write them to an audio CD. Instead of directly writing to an optical disk, I would prefer to somehow redirect the output to an image file which can be burned later.

Specifically, I attempted the following steps:

1. create a file to be written to (700 MiB, 777 permissions)

   ```
   dd if=/dev/zero of=./cd.img bs=$((1024 * 1024)) count=700
   ```
2. attach file to loop device (`/dev/loop0`, as `root`)

   ```
   losetup --sizelimit 700MiB /dev/loop0 ./cd.img
   ```
3. use `mp3cd` software to convert, normalize ... and ultimately write audio files to audio CD (as root)

   ```
   mp3cd --verbose --driver generic-mmc-raw --device /dev/loop0 ./audio/{01..03}.mp3
   ```

`mp3cd` fails on its last step, "burn". The file `/tmp/mp3cd-root/tool-output.txt` contains a hint that an SCSI command inquiry on `/dev/loop0` failed. Most likely, I am missing some options in the `losetup` command.

In addition to achieving the image creation in this particular case of an audio cd, I would be thankful for some pointers on how images for data CDs/DVDs could be prepared in a similar way.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried passing the option -n to mp3cd?

On the man page http://outflux.net/unix/software/mp3cd/mp3cd.html :

> -n, --simulate     Don't actually burn a disc but do everything else.

Comment: That yields exit code 25, with the following output: 'cdrdao read-test  --device /dev/loop0 cdda.toc >>tool-output.txt 2>&1' 'Checking for CDR...' 'cdrdao disk-info  --device /dev/loop0' 'CDR not loaded?!'

Comment: forgot to mention: during simulation, all steps before the loop device access are completed without trouble.

Comment: What appears it mp3cd uses cdrdao to write to CD and it is using some commands that are specific to CD, and losetup don't support it, I think.

I used some time ago the k3b to make iso so it may resolve your issue. Downsides, isn't a text application and need a lot of stuff from kde ...

Comment: exactly. mp3cd can be instructed to do every preparatory step except the burning itself, so normalized wav files and a toc file, the basis for audio cd creation, are generated. If another commandline tool could be used for the actual image creation, the problem at hand would be solved. Nonetheless, i'd like to understand how an optical drive could be emulated in general.

Comment: I don't know if the files have any order or something special in the way they are treated, but you can use mkisofs to generate an iso of the files generated and cdrecord to save it to a cd http://linux.die.net/man/8/mkisofs

Normally cd emulation is mounting iso disks or similars to be accessible, simulate the hardware version don't know if is possible. Exist a cdemu utility but never used.

Comment: iso images have some filesystem structure, which is not required for audio disks, afaik. But the cdemu hint looks promising - i will try that out and report back (which might take a few days). Thanks so far!

Comment: If you have "normalized wav files and a toc file", that pretty much *is* the "image file which can be burned later" that you're looking for.  There is no other image file that gets produced after that, only physical sectors burned on a disc.